# REST API JSON error code and error message

Tags: json, api, rest, standards

I have been writing Web Services from a recent past, this is a sample success and error response.

**error**

```
{
  "code": 1150,
  "status": false,
  "message": "API Student does not exist.",
  "serverTime": "2013-11-29 09:47:52"
}
```

**success**

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 49
  },
  "serverTime": "2014-04-17 05:06:17"
}
```

With regards to returning errors I have a confusion, why do we always return one error code and one message, for example, when username and password is required as input params, say a blank request is made, so what I return is a **error code 1100** and **error message "Username is incorrect"**. I never return the whole list of errors, for example, in this case, two error message with two error codes should be sent so it saves end users data & time.

This is a sample of what I suggest?

```
{
  "code": 1010,
  "status": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 1000,
      "name": "Username invalid"
    },
    {
      "code": 1001,
      "name": "Password invalid"
    },
        {
      "code": 1002,
      "name": "Password not strong"
    }
  ],
  "serverTime": "2013-12-03 12:34:02"
}
```

Why is this not a good way to do? I have not seen this in either Twitter API or Facebook API.

Comment: In regard to facebook for example it would be a leak of security telling all fields that are wrong. This bundle of information would make a bruteforce much easier/faster.

As well as your Application-Code is proceeding simple sequences and at one point something unexpected happens, then you return the error. Why would go keep proceeding to collect more errors?

In your case i would simply avoid sending empty formulars by html/js checks before (HTML-Input-Tag: required="required")

Comment: I think security is not a problem, because those are already exposed via mobile screens assuming this is a login screen or sign up screen of a mobile app. may be this would save end user's time and reduce the number of api calls without making several api calls to retrieve errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody can stop API designers to return multiple possible error responses. **Decision is up to them only** but in my opinion you should return most relevant error occurred from server side.

There can be many reasons behind it like below :

> 1. Unified Error Handling by all clients.
> 2. Most relevant error caused will help client more actually as he will not have to take care  about all probabilistic error caused.
> 3. JSON structure simplicity. ( Error Array will be avoided. )

Comment: @timeman789 -  I'll always go with single  most relevant error.